# Rails 4 Trying to connect CSS attribute to the view

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a grid of videos on a page that pop up in a light box when clicked. I want the title of the video to show up if the user hovers over the grid image.

Right now, on hover, I get the desired background for the title, but I can't figure out where/how to put the css attribute for the video title in my html.erb

Here's the CSS:

```
.masonry:hover .item.w2:hover:after {
    content: attr(datatitle);
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
     height: 40px;
     opacity:0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Here's my view:

```
<div class="item w2" ><%= link_to image_tag(Video.find(19).image_url, size: "250x141"), Video.find(19).player_embed_url, class: "fancybox fancybox.iframe"%>
```

Where do I put the datatitle attribute and how? I'll want to pull the title of the video with the same method above (i.e. Video.find(19).title)

For reference, here is a jsfiddle I was using to craft this:

http://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/chbsL3pq/

But obviously, I want to pull the Title from the Video object, not hardcode it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add:

```
data: { title: 'title goes here' }
```

to the link_to:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(Video.find(19).image_url, size: "250x141"), Video.find(19).player_embed_url, class: "fancybox fancybox.iframe", data: { title: 'title goes here' } %>
```

Comment: I tried just adding the `data: {title: 'title goes here'}` as you suggested as well as `data: { title: Video.find(19).title }` but nothing is happening. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: when you add `data` what html is generated by rails. Can you check in the browser's inspector?

Comment: using `data: {title: 'title goes here'}` in ERB

HTML:
`<div class="masonry js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 50, "gutter": 15 }'>
<div class="item w2"><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-title="title goes here" href="http://app.ustudio.com/embed/D6rHaGhIFLIV/UlSUJO6watDt"><img src="https://ce70e1713c6d8fc9cdd0-27f5abc5a0ea24152d882b2f1ce8ed03.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/IuQZuq34SGVW.jpg" alt="Iuqzuq34sgvw" width="250" height="141" /></a></div>`

Comment: Ok I think this is not a rails issue but an issue with your css/html. I think with your current css sure you will need to move data-tile to `item w2` element: Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/dedolereyi/1/edit?html,css,output Also make sure to use `content: attr(data-title)` instead of `content: attr(datatitle)`

Comment: Progress! The title attr in my view wasn't in the right place. I moved it to the first div `<div class="item w2" data-title = "Ender's Game"` and moved data-title to `item w2` element. I already learned a ton, thanks! 

Followup - how would I now change `data-title = "Ender's Game"` to something like `data-title = (Video.find(19).title)` within the div? When I try exactly that it just returns the string. 

That's just a bonus, if you have time. Accepting your answer!

Comment: Nevermind, got it! `<div class="item w2" data-title = "<%= Video.find(19).title %>"` Thanks a lot for your help!